# How to increase precision with division in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a sql query `select 1/3`, and it returns `0.33333`.  Is there any way to increase precision to 20 decimal places?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using decimal precision:

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(30, 20)) / 3 AS output FROM dual;
```

Note here that I first cast `1` to a decimal with 20 places of decimal precision.  Then we divide this by `3`, but using the same precision.

Your example is somewhat contrived, because in practice if you required 20 decimal places of precision you would define the relevant columns to be numeric or decimal.  Then you would not need an explicit cast.

### Demo